# Does anyone know where I can find a memory editing user control for .net?

Tags: .net, .net-2.0, binary-data, user-controls, memory-editing

I am developing a small application which lists the contents from files of a given format. The file format acts as a template for describing binary data (think binary xml). This allows the clients that produces these files to store data in any way they want, so the interpretion of **all types** contained **are not known**. What I would like to do is to browse through these types, interpret the common types, and expose a sort of memory editor for unknown types.

The basic rundown is that I have a byte buffer which I am going to manipulate through a user interface.

I am looking for some user controls for .net which hopefully has done this already. If not, I suppose I'll have to write my own. Please send me links to existing assemblies

Comment: He is looking for a 3rd party module to help him with a specific task - and that task sounds like programming to me!

Comment: Yes - I have tried google. All I found was articles on memory debugging, memory editing software.. All but what I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This project claims to have a reusable hex editor component: [Be.HexEditor](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hexbox/) - that would probably be the best way to edit random binary data.

Comment: NIce find. Have you used this control?

Comment: This looks exactly like what I need. Will try it ASAP. Many thanks!